# expanding jooq's row value query

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Using jooq to generate query for MySQL and checking if the row value clause generated by it can be expanded since mysql is not able to use indexes properly in row value queries

for example

```java
DSLContext context = new DefaultDSLContext(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
SelectQuery<Record> select = context.selectQuery();
select.addSelect(field("Col1"));
select.addFrom(table("Table1").as("T1"));
select.addOrderBy(field("Name"), field("Sid"));
select.addSeekAfter(param("p2", "John"), param("p3","123"));
String generated = select.getSQL(ParamType.NAMED);
```

produces following query

```sql
where (1 = 1 and (Name, Id) > (:p2, :p3)) order by Name asc, Id asc
```

but will like to be

```
where Name > :p2 or (Name = :p2 and Id > :p3) order by Name asc, Id asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently (jOOQ 3.9, see [#6230](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6230)) not possible to override this behaviour. You'll have to add an explicit predicate of the form you'd like it to be.